# Should I use an Exception in a case like this?

Tags: design, exceptions

I have a Windows service with a fluent interface like this:

```
aRequest = Repository.getRequest()
                     .createProcess()
                     .validate();
```

Sometimes `getRequest()` could return a `null` value and this would cause an error in `createProcess()`. I could banally split `getRequest()` from `createProcess()`, but if I wouldn't do that what way should I follow, what way is better:

- Check if request (`this`) is null and in the case return null:

  ```
  if(this is null)
    return null
  ```

  I could do this check in every method next to `getRequest()`. At the end `aRequest` will be `null`.
- Throw an exception if `createProcess()` method receive a `null` value:

  ```
  if(this is null)
     throw new NullRequestException();
  ```

PRO of the second way: Only second method need a check, independently of the number of method in the chain.

CON of the first way: Every method in the chain needs a check

Now the question: Is second way a bad use of exception concept, since could be normal the absence of request sometimes?

Comment: I'd say the answer is "neither", because [`null` is considered harmful](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/q/12777/116461) and [there are better alternatives](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/UsingAndAvoidingNullExplained). If an `Optional` type isn't your cup of tea, then throw an exception from the `getRequest` method.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to maintain the fluent syntax, **`getRequest()` must never return null!** The fluent interface must return `this` at every step, and `this` can't be null. ;)

If the internal call inside getRequest returns a null, then you need to change the state of Repository so that `validate()` can pick up that condition and throw an exception or handle it appropriately. You could have a member variable "String answer;" and set & check that for null, or else have a "boolean nullAnswer;" member.

Also, take a look at Guava's "Optional" class, because it's a great way of handling values that might not be present. Even then, make sure your fluent methods *always* returns `this` (or the variant `return new Respository(...)`).

Answer (score 1):

Is it possible to not return `null` from `getRequest()`, or at least have a separate version of it doing so? If it threw an exception instead, and other parts of the chain would do the same,  you'd have a nice consistent error handling.

What a pity that both Java and C# lack the `Maybe` and `Either` idioms; `Optional` has seen some adoption, though. Returning `null` is a bad idea: it hides the source of your problem. It is infuriating during troubleshooting. In general, fail fast, right where the problem occurs. I'd use exceptions.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is fine that `getRequest` returns `null`, so long as the reader knows that it can.

The problem of your example, the way it's written, it reads as it should 100% of the time it will create a process.

If the expectation is that `getRequest` should never return null, then that method should be the one throwing the exception.  If it's expected that `getRequest` returns null instead, you should modify your usage of it to handle that case.

```
private Request createProcessIfRequestFound() {
    var request = Repository.getRequest();

    if (request != null) {
        request.createProcess().validate(); 
    }

    return request;
}
```

My personal preference is to avoid fluent interfaces, in my opinion, ironically, I find they are less fluent than writing code non-"fluently"